Im trying to send a dm on join im using discord.py==2.3.2
It does not send a dm i was using my alt which has never joined the server
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    try:
        await member.send(f"Welcome to .LDQ {member.mention}!")
    except discord.Forbidden:
        print(f"Failed to send a DM to {member.name} on join. (Forbidden: Missing Permissions)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to send a DM to {member.name} on join. Error: {e}")



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Fixed i didnt have intents.members

Brother, first google why you can't send dm messages on google. I'm pretty sure there is a few of them having the same intent problem.

@Brawldude2 yeah i figured it out 2 seconds after i posted this lol
